Compilation error : Isolated expression [Metapost]
I don't understand the error generated by the compilation of this code which does not work (based on an idea from Franck Pastor Area between two curves
beginfig(1);

interim linejoin := mitered;
interim ahangle := 30;

numeric u, pi, a, b;

pi = 3.141592653589793;
u = 1.5cm;

vardef graph_of_function (suffix f) (expr xmin, xmax, xsep) =
    for x = xmin step xsep until xmax: (x, f(x)) .. endfor (xmax, f(xmax))
enddef ;

vardef vline (suffix f, g) (expr x) = (x, min(f(x), g(x))) -- (x, max(f(x),g(x))) 
enddef;


vardef area_between_functions (suffix f, g)(expr a, b, xsep) =
      buildcycle(graph_of_function(f, a, b, xsep), vline(f, g, b), 
      reverse graph_of_function(g, a, b, xsep), reverse vline(f, g, a))
enddef;


xmin :=-pi/2; xmax := 3*pi/2; 
ymin :=-1.5; ymax  := 5;

vardef f(expr x)= exp(-x)*(-cos(x)+sin(x)+1) enddef;
vardef g(expr x)=-exp(-x)*cos(x) enddef;

path C_f, C_g;

C_f = graph_of_function(f,xmin,xmax,0.01);
C_g = graph_of_function(g,xmin,xmax,0.01);

a = xpart(C_f intersectionpoint C_g); 
b = xpart(reverse C_f intersectionpoint reverse C_g);

fill (area_between_functions(f, g, a, b, 0.1)) scaled u withcolor 0.4[white, blue];
draw C_f scaled u withcolor blue;
draw C_g scaled u withcolor blue;
  
endfig;

Here's the console output
MPtoPDF 1.4.1 : running 'mpost --mem=mpost  logo.mp'
This is MetaPost, version 2.10 (TeX Live 2024) (kpathsea version 6.4.0)
(/home/fabrice/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/home/fabrice/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./logo.mp
>> exp
! Isolated expression.
<to be read again>
                   (
f->begingroup.exp(
                  -(EXPR2))*(-cos((EXPR2))+sin((EXPR2))+1)endgroup
<for(-1.5708)> ((EXPR0),f((EXPR0))
                                  ).. ENDFOR
graph_of_function->...R4):(x,(SUFFIX2)(x))..endfor
                                                  ((EXPR4),(SUFFIX2)((EXPR4)...
l.33 C_f = graph_of_function(f,xmin,xmax,0.01)
                                              ;
[...]
Transcript written on logo.log.

MPtoPDF 1.4.1 : error while processing mp file


Please link to the sources of code you are using. A name is good, but it would have been a whole lot easier to answer this if you'd included a link. I could also now give you a better explanation, because I could point specifically to the context you're missing.
In the absence of such information, just compile with
mpost --mem=metafun --numbersystem=double <filename>.mp

I would post an image, but the latest Okular-on-X produces output which would put readers off MetaPost permanently and that would be most unfair.
I used Franck Pastor's answer but I've no idea if that's what the OP used. I assume metafun is doing the work here. double just doubles the precision.


Thanks, the code compiles with this command. I added the link in my original question.

@Fabrice Thanks. Glad it helped ;).
